# Truncation (24-bit Audio Processing)

Tags: android, audio

I wish to examine the most appropriate means by which to process 24-bit .WAV files, while targeting two specific sampling frequencies: 96000 & 192000 Hz. In order to avoid truncation back to PCM 16-bit (and with Android 4.3 in mind), might one assume that a custom audio interface is the only feasible option?

Comment: This question needs a lot more detail.  You certainly won't be capturing anything at either 96k or 192k on an Android device, so I assume your WAV files are at this SFC?

Comment: Marko - I assume by 'SFC' you mean: Sound File Converter! The question was posed to achieve a better understanding about Android, in order to develop a 'next generation' Android device.

Comment: sorry that should have been Fsc which is common engineering notation for Sample frequency.

Comment: Marko - I have today made contact (e-mail) with: Prossimo Ventures.